# Is there a simpler way to use interfaces in F# implicitly?

Tags: interface, f#

I am playing a bit with F# interfaces, by creating a simple data access class.

The interface is:

```
type IUserAccess =
    abstract member GetUsers : (dbSchema.ServiceTypes.Users -> bool) -> dbSchema.ServiceTypes.Users seq 
    abstract member GetAllUsers : unit -> dbSchema.ServiceTypes.Users seq
```

In the class, I am calling the methods in this way:

```
type UserAccess() = 
    let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
    interface IUserAccess with
        member this.GetUsers cond  =
            let query = query {
                for row in db.Users do
                select row } 
            query |> Seq.where cond

        member this.GetAllUsers () =
            (this:>IUserAccess).GetUsers (fun _ -> true)
```

What I'm a bit concerned with is the way I am calling `GetAllUsers` function, specifically with part `(this:>IUserAccess)`. What is the simplest way of calling methods that are implemented within the same interface?

One simple option I can think of is creating `GetUsers` method directly within `UserAccess()` class and then calling it from the interface implementation of both `GetUsers` and `GetAllUsers`, but that means a new private method implemented, which I would like to avoid. Is there another option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F# always implements interfaces explicitly, so your options are pretty much as you stated, but you can avoid redundant casting by introducing a let binding:

```
type IUserAccess =
    interface
        abstract member GetUsers : (obj -> bool) -> unit
        abstract member GetAllUsers : unit -> unit
    end

type Foo() as self =
    let userAccess = self :> IUserAccess
    interface IUserAccess with
        member this.GetUsers(q : (obj -> bool)) : unit =
           ()
        member this.GetAllUsers() =
            userAccess.GetUsers(fun _ -> true)
```

I just simplified your interface and object so I could get something compiling real quick.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the simple improvement I was looking for!

Answer (score 8):

I think the solution by @vcsjones is probably the best option if you want to avoid defining a separate method directly inside the class. That said, declaring a separate method is actually not that ugly. You can use local definition using `let` binding (which is automatically compiled as a private method) and I think it makes the code look quite nice:

```
type UserAccess() = 
    let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
    let getUsers cond = 
      let query = query {
          for row in db.Users do
          select row } 
      query |> Seq.where cond

    interface IUserAccess with
        member this.GetUsers cond  = getUsers cond
        member this.GetAllUsers () = getUsers (fun _ -> true)
```

I generally quite like this style, because it separates all the private implementation from the part of the definition where you're defining the public exposed API.